# Probability of drawing three consecutive cards values out of five

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I draw five cards. What's the probability that there is a subset of these cards that makes a run of three or more consecutive card values (e.g., 5-6-7 or 10-J-Q).
So far I have written the code for this and these are the results:
Number of trials: 1000000
Number of wins: 205961
Number of losses: 794039
Estimated probability of winning: 0.205961

But I can't figure out the formula.

Comment: Do you allow an Ace to be both the low card and the high card?

Comment: No, first draw:  p = 1 
Second draw
if (First = ace || 2 ): p =4/51
(anything else):p =  8/51

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{52}{5}=2,598,960$ possible five-card hands. Checking all of them with a bit of code gives the following results:

If A-2-3 and Q-K-A both qualify (as they should) then there are $625,472$ qualifying hands. $P\approx 0.24$

Otherwise there are $575,184$ qualifying hands. $P\approx 0.22$ (This suggests a flaw in your code)

Comment: I'll try to figure out a combinatorics solution, but  make no promises.

Comment: Yes, I have found a problem in my code. You are right, the probability is 0.22. Thank you!